# ng2 chart multiple chart update

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

in my code, I get server data for monitoring, using API
And I have multiple Charts, all the charts working fine, so I update my charts every 1 second, and I call API from the server every 1 second also, but only my first chart will update others not, any solution ??
note: I am using ng2-chart by valor-software

```js
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceService } from '../api-service.service';
import { Observable , interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {IData} from '../interface/data'
import { BaseChartDirective} from 'ng2-charts';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;
//==================================================
import { Servers } from '../custom-config/servers'; // Servers Data
import {lineChart} from '../custom-config/chart-config'// chart Configration Data


@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-monit',
  templateUrl: './server-monit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-monit.component.css'],
})
export class ServerMonitComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild( BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
 
  public _servers= Servers;
  //==========================================
  //  time 
  pipe = new DatePipe('en-US'); // Use your own locale
  public now;
  public currentTime;

  //==========================================
  // Line Chart configration
  public chartType = 'line';
  public chartLegend = true;
  public chartColor = '#eee'
  public chartOptions = lineChart.Options
  public colors = lineChart.Colors


  constructor(private api: ApiServiceService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this._servers.length; i++ ) {
      // get data on Init
      this.api.checkServer(this._servers[i].ip+':'+this._servers[i].port).subscribe((data:IData) => {
        this.proccessData(data, i)
      });
      // get  data every subsequent 1 seconds
    const result = interval(1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.api.checkServer(this._servers[i].ip+':'+this._servers[i].port)),)
    .subscribe((data:IData) => {
      this.proccessData(data, i) // proccess the APIdata 
      this.forceChartRefresh(); // Update charts
    });
    }
  }

  proccessData(data: IData , index){
    
      this.now = Date.now();
      this.currentTime = this.pipe.transform(this.now, 'mediumTime');
      //=============================================================
      let totalClients = data.total_clients;
      let input = Math.round(data.input_kbit  /1024);
      let output = Math.round(data.output_kbit /1024);

      if(
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[0].data.length <= 20 &&
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[1].data.length <= 20 &&
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[2].data.length <= 20
      ){
      this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[0].data.push(totalClients)
      this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[1].data.push(input)
      this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[2].data.push(output)
      this._servers[index].charts.traffic.labels.push(this.currentTime)
      }
      else {
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[0].data.shift()
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[1].data.shift()
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.dataset[2].data.shift()
        this._servers[index].charts.traffic.labels.shift()

      }
      
  }

  forceChartRefresh() {
    this.chart.chart.update()
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  server-monit works!
</p>
<div class="col-4" *ngFor="let server of _servers">
  <div>
  <canvas     baseChart 
              [datasets]="server.charts.traffic.dataset"
              [labels]="server.charts.traffic.labels"
              [options]="chartOptions"
              [colors]=""
              [legend]="chartLegend"
              [chartType]="chartType"
              ></canvas>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes and all the data updated correctly with the timer

Comment: `_server` is an object contains eath server IP port and Datasets

Comment: ChangeDetectRef how ??

Comment: `@ViewChild( BaseChartDirective,{read: ChangeDetectRef) chart: BaseChartDirective;` like that ??

Comment: it is not updating any of the charts

Comment: yes I included the line inside forceChartRefresh()

Comment: What I doubt is: you are getting data for first call and refreshes, then you are getting again another data for second call it refreshes again... What you need is to restructure you calls. Refresh once you got all the data. And make sure you are getting data before it hits 1 second.

Comment: 1 second , i run log it is one second

Answer (score 15, accepted):

after some research I found the issue :
the issue is the:

```
@ViewChild( BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

it only selects the first child, so

```
this.chart.chart.update()
```

only update the first child , the solution is: should use QueryList

```
@ViewChildren(BaseChartDirective) charts: QueryList<BaseChartDirective>;
```

and update the list :

```
  this.charts.forEach((child) => {
      child.chart.update()
  });
```

Comment: @Diniya I found this helpful, but may I ask why is this so ? have you found anything regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this, create an data object and a labels object with in your current object. as you get your graph data from your data source you'll probably have to modify it to fit the pattern of the graph that you have working, then iterate over all of your objects and plug in the graph data.

this all happens during a click event, I use Angular 8. Message me if you need help.

(properties in a model below)

```
public barChartData: any[] = [{ data: [], label: 'Red' }, { data: [], label: 'Blue' }],
public barChartLabels: any[] = [""]

this.redBlueCountByDate.forEach((item) => {

  barChartLabels.push(new Date(item.eomDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
  barChartData[0].data.push(item.redDataCount);
  barChartData[1].data.push(item.blueDataCount);            
})

this.modelData.find(x => x.dataID == dataID).barChartData = barChartData;
this.modelData.find(x => x.dataID == dataID).barChartLabels = barChartLabels;
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in other answer the update works only on the first chart. It seems that to update a chart you need to make a "clone" of its ChartDataSets and not just update the dataset or labels but reassign the whole variable.
You can see an issue on this case on github : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/865

The solution to make it work :

```
//You have a dataset as an attribute of your component
public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  { data: [1, 2, 3], label: 'Approved', stack: 'a' },
  { data: [1, 2, 3], label: 'Accepted', stack: 'a' },
];
//In your update function just clone the dataset 
//Then update it with new data and reassign it to the attribute barChartData
update(){
  const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.barChartData));
  clone[0].data = data;
  this.barChartData = clone;
}
```

A stackblitz to demonstrate the answer I found : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-multiple-charts-tcc6ds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts